# How to calculate discrete and continuous Raiffa solution in a bargain problem

Tags: limits, game-theory, recursive-algorithms

In a bargain problem $(N,F,d)$ in which:

$N$ = Number of players.

$F$ = Feasible agreements set.

$d$ = Disagreement point.

We can define discrete Raiffa solution as:

$$DR(N,F,d)=\lim_{k\to\infty} d^k$$

And continous Raiffa solution as:

$$CR(N,F,d)=\lim_{\delta\to0} d(\delta)$$
with
$$d(\delta)=\lim_{k\to\infty} d^k(\delta)$$

How can I calculate both solutions for $N=\{1,2\}$, $d=(0,0)$ and $F=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x \leq 2,y \leq 1, x+3y \leq 3 \}$?